# File_get_contents() turned bidimensional array in string: how can ricreate it?

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

i have a file `array48.php` where inside there's a bidimensional array:

```
$bidim= array(
 array(1,2),
 array(3,4),
 array('ok','end')
);
```

I have to do some operations on this array so, to include the file, i would use `file_get_contents()` (file is on my server) but with this function the array turned to string.

How can ricreate the same bidimensional array ?

For me is a problem to try because is haven't yet this file (will receive for work among next weeks).

**EDIT**:

Then, in same file, i delete `array48.php` and create a **new** `array48.php` file with new bidimensional array (where will be the updated array). I read that in this case, use other function like `include()` could be a problem.... is right ?

I hope you can help me.... thanks a lot !

P.S. sorry for my english

Comment: Use `json_encode` and `json_decode` if you need to read and write the file.